# Python MySQLdb update query fails

Tags: python, mysql

Okay. I've built here a mysql query browser, like navicat. Using MySQLdb to perform queries.

Here's the weird part. When i run the query through the program(using MySQLdb), it gives me success, affected rows = 1, but when i look at it in phpmyadmin, the value hasn't changed.

so before i perform the query, i  print it out, copy and paste into phpmyadmin's query window, hit go and it works. So long story short, update query isn't working, but when i copy and paste into phpmyadmin, it works.

```
self.tbl.sql.use(self.tbl.database)       # switches to correct database. I've printed this and it uses the corrected db
if self.tbl.sql.execute(query) == True:
    print sql_obj.rows_affected()         # returns 1 (since i only do 1 query)
```

And here's the part of the SQL class

```
def execute(self, query):

    try:
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        return True
    except MySQLdb.ProgrammingError as error:
        print "---->SQL Error: %s" % error
        return False
    except MySQLdb.IntegrityError as e:
        print "--->SQL Error: %s" % e    
        return False
```

So any ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just a guess: Perhaps the code in Python is running within a transaction, and the transaction might need to be explicitly committed?

Edit: There's an [entry in the MySQLdb FAQ](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away) that might be relevant.

Comment: +1: No commit means the change is invisible to everyone else.

Answer (score 20):

I believe @Jason Creighton and @S.Lott are correct.

At least if the table that you're updating is on a transactional storage engine. `InnoDB` is transactional, `ISAM` is not.

You either have to call `commit()` on your connection object before closing it, or you must set the connection to autocommit mode. I am not sure how you do that for a MySQLdb connection, I guess you either set an argument to the connection constructor, or set a property after creating the connection object.

Something like:

```
conn = mysql.connection(host, port, autocommit=True)

# or
conn = mysql.connection(host, port)
conn.autocommit(True)
```

Comment: Ahh i see. Yes this was the problem.
Although you did post the answer answer straight forward, I will have to mark Jason's as the accepted one, as he answered first, with a link to the solution. Thanks very much though, I will give it 1+! :)

Comment: Yep! Your second guess is the right one -- conn.autocommit(True) works (though explicit commits are still better;-).