# Python MySQL - SELECTs work but not DELETEs?

Tags: python, mysql, select, sql-delete

I'm new to Python and Python's MySQL adapter.  I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious here:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(# db details omitted)
cursor = self.db.cursor()

# WORKS
cursor.execute("SELECT site_id FROM users WHERE username=%s", (username))
record = cursor.fetchone()

# DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE username=%s", (username))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what privileges do you have on the databases?

Comment: yes be sure that the user you are using has the rights to delete rows.

Comment: When you say "DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK": how do you know? Do you get some kind of error message? If so, which one? Please report all details upfront.

Comment: Apologies.  By does not seem to work, I mean that if I run SELECT * FROM users; at the mysql console, I still see the row there.  There is no error message at all.

The user has full privileges.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd guess that you are using a storage engine that supports transactions (e.g. InnoDB) but you don't call `db.commit()` after the DELETE.  The effect of the DELETE is discarded if you don't commit.

See http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away:

> Starting with 1.2.0, MySQLdb disables
>   autocommit by default, as required by
>   the DB-API standard (PEP-249). If you
>   are using InnoDB tables or some other
>   type of transactional table type,
>   you'll need to do connection.commit()
>   before closing the connection, or else
>   none of your changes will be written
>   to the database.

See also this similar SO question:  [Python MySQLdb update query fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028671/python-mysqldb-update-query-fails)

Comment: Bingo!  This is the Python-specific thing I was looking for, because the above would have worked in straight up PHP or Ruby with no problem.  Thanks guys!

Comment: broke my head with this yesterday... took a while to figure out why.  Do you think there is a performance gain of committing everything at once?  ie, instead of deleting for every instance in a for loop, committing at the end before close?

Comment: Yes, there's definitely a performance gain.  For example, the default config for InnoDB does an `fsync()` after every transaction commit.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are violating a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

To your code above, 
just add a call to `self.db.commit()`.

The feature is far from an annoyance:

It saves you from data corruption issues 
when there are errors in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are not committing the changes. it can be done by 
`conn.commit()`

read more on this [here](http://sahanlm.blogspot.com/2012/10/mysqldb-does-not-commit-then-read-this.html)