# python MySQLdb wont insert into db

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Hi I have an issue with inserting  info to my db. It doesn't give off an error.The code is here.

```py
import MySQLdb as m

def Room(room):
   db = m.connect("localhost","root","password","rooms")
   cur = db.cursor()
   cur.execute('INSERT INTO rooms (name) VALUES("%s");'% (room))
def getRoomDb():
   db = m.connect("localhost","root","password","rooms")
   cur = db.cursor()
   cur.execute("SELECT * FROM rooms;")
   result = cur.fetchall()
   return result

print getRoomDb()
```

after i run the `Room("roomname")` it outputs like it should but nothing actually gets put into the db

Comment: How about commit() your data?

Comment: how would i use that I'm new to mysql and python

Comment: you're not calling the Room() function either...

Comment: I do just I eval it on bot

Comment: if i run the Room() as print Room("roomname") it outputs none

Comment: THANK YOU ALL XDD PROBLEM SOVED I NEEDED THE db.commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't call `commit()` for the transaction in which you executed the INSERT.

In Python, the default action is to roll back work, unless you explicitly commit.

See also:

- [Python MySQL - SELECTs work but not DELETEs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451782/python-mysql-selects-work-but-not-deletes/)
- [Python MySQLdb update query fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028671/python-mysqldb-update-query-fails)
- http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away