# Not showing data in database after insertion using python

Tags: python, mysql

I am using python 2.7 and MySQL as database. In my python program have an `INSERT` query like this:

```
cursor.execute("insert into login(username,passw)values('"+i.username+"','"+i.password+"')")
result=cursor.execute("select * from login")
print cursor.fetchall()
```

When I check in the database, there is no entry. But after the select in my python code, when I print the results it is showing the inserted data. I am not using any transaction statement either.

Comment: You need to commit those changes. `connection.commit()`

Answer (score 5):

You need to *commit* your transaction for the database to make your insert permanent, and you need to use SQL parameters to prevent SQL injection attacks and general quoting bugs:

```
cursor.execute("insert into login (username, passw) values (%s, %s)", (i.username, i.password))
connection.commit()
```

Until you commit, the data you inserted will only be visible to your python program; if you do not commit at all, then the changes will be *discarded* again by the database.

Alternatively, you could switch on auto-commit mode:

```
connection.autocommit()
```

After switching on auto-commit, your insertions will be committed *instantly*. Be careful with this as this could lead to inconsistent data if you need to insert data into multiple rows and  / or tables that is interdependent.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to [commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) the data after your execution statement. It is important to call this method after you are done inserting, or updating data, as the Python connector does not [auto commit by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-autocommit.html).

```
# Execute & Commit
cursor.execute("insert into login(username,passw) values('%s','%s')", 
               i.username, i.password)
# Commit the insert query!
conn.commit() 

# Fetch Result
result=cursor.execute("select * from login")
print cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysql-python, you can set connection options to enable autocommit feature.

```
conn = mysql.connection(host, port, autocommit=True)

# or
conn = mysql.connection(host, port)
conn.autocommit(True)
```

You can see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029016/260793)